# Test validity of a product for a store view transparently

Tags: ce-1.9.2.2

There are a number of conditions that determine if a product can be displayed in a certain store view. From the top of my head, I know 3:

- Is the product associated with the website?
- Is the product configured as enabled/active for that website?
- Does the product have a non-empty price field for that store view?

Background is that I have an external search function using a Solr server in the backend. That search function has been altered so that when a product number is entered into the search function and enter is pressed and there is a product matching that product number close to 100% (capitalization is ignored, but otherwise it needs to be a match), then it jumps directly to the product detail page, otherwise a normal search is performed.

Now, it dawned on me that I could in that way find a product that is not visible to the store view (see the conditions above). The result is that the URL is called correctly, but results in a 404.

Is there a transparent way of testing if a product could theoretically be viewed for a certain store view without finding and spelling out the exhaustive list as it currently is? I imagine something like

```
Mage::Helper('something')->canViewInStoreview($productId, $storeviewId)
```

would be right on the spot. If spelled out, the conditions in the next version could change, and I would not want to re-check with every update if the list is still complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you got it all covered.

- The product needs to be assigned to the current website
- The product needs to be enabled.
- The product needs to have the visibility `catalog` or `catalog & search` in order to appear when browsing the catalog. And `search` or `catalog & search` when using the search functionality.

I don't know about the 0 price. I think products with 0 price can be displayed.

But to make sure, you can follow the trace starting from the product controller view action.

`Mage_Catalog_ProductController::viewAction`.
This one calls `$viewHelper->prepareAndRender($productId, $this, $params);` which means `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_View::prepareAndRender()`.
This one calls  `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product::initProduct`.

and this one contains:

```
    if (!$this->canShow($product)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!in_array(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId(), $product->getWebsiteIds())) {
        return false;
    }
```

Which basically means (`canShow`) if the product exists, is enabled and has the proper visibility it's OK. The next `if` checks if the product is assigned to the current website.

But you should also be careful at the custom code you have that hook onto some events dispatched in `prepareAndRender` method and the ones that are called from it.

Comment: The price field condition was referring to an empty field, not a "0.00" value. You can get empty price fields using importers. I'll implement your version and accept, if it works. Thanks so far.

Comment: It works very well, although I wasn't able to instantiate the respective helper class in my module. I'm doing the checks manually, and the customers are happy. Thank you.